# Look up data frame with values stored in another data frame

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have 15 data frames containing information about patient visits for a group of patients. Example below. They are named as FA.OFC1, FA.OFC2 etc.

```
ID       sex   date        age.yrs   important.var   etc...
xx_111   F     xx.xx.xxxx  x.x       x
```

I am generating a summary data frame (`sev.scores`) which contains information about the most severe episode a patient has across all recorded data. I have successfully used the `which.max` function to get the most severe episode but now need additional information about that particular episode.

I recreated the name of the data frame I will need to look up to get the additional information by pasting information after the max return:

```
max        data frame
8          df2
```

Specifically the `names()` function gave me the name of the column with the most severe episode (in the summary data frame `sev.scores` which also gives me information about which data frame to look up:

```
sev.scores[52:53] <- as.data.frame(cbind(row.names(sev.scores[c(5,8,11,14,17,20,23,26,29,32,35,38,41,44,47,50)]),apply(sev.scores[c(5,8,11,14,17,20,23,26,29,32,35,38,41,44,47,50)],1,function(x) names(sev.scores[c(5,8,11,14,17,20,23,26,29,32,35,38,41,44,47,50)])[which(x==max(x))])))
```

However now I would like to figure out how to tell R to take the data frame name stored in the column and search that data frame for the entry in the 5th column.

So in the example above the information about the most severe episode is stored in data frame 2 (`df2`) and I need to take information from the 5th record (`important.var`) and return it to this summary data frame.

UPDATE

I have now stored these dfs in a list but am still having some trouble getting the information I would like.

I found the following example for getting the max value from a list

```
lapply(L1, function(x) x[which.max(abs(x))])
```

How can I adapt this for a factor which is present in all elements of the list?

e.g. something like:

```
lapply(my_dfs[[all elements]]["factor of interest"], function(x) x[which.max(abs(x))])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I may suggest a fundamentally different approach: concatenate all your data.frames into *one* (`rbind`), and add  a separate column that describes the nature of the original data.frame. For this, it’s necessary to know in which regard the original data.frames differed (e.g. by disease type; since I don’t know your data, let’s stick with this for my example).

Furthermore, you need to ensure that your data is in [tidy data format](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyr/vignettes/tidy-data.html). This is an easy requirement to satisfy, because [*your data should be in this format anyway*](http://varianceexplained.org/r/tidy-genomics-biobroom/)!

Then, once you have all the data in a single data.frame, you can create a summary trivially by simply selecting the most severe episode for each disease type:

```
sev_scores = all_data %>%
    group_by(ID) %>%
    filter(row_number() == which.max(FactorOfInterest))
```

Note that this code uses the ‹dplyr› package. You can perform an equivalent analysis using different packages (e.g. ‹data.table›) or base R functions, but I strongly recommend dplyr: [The resulting code is generally easier to understand.](http://varianceexplained.org/r/teach-tidyverse/)

Rather than your `sev.scores` table, which has columns referring to rows and data.frame names, the `sev_scores` I created above will contain the *actual data* for the most severe episode for each patient ID.

Comment: Thanks! I have combined the data.frames as suggested but run across an issue with duplicated column names. I can rename them but then using `which.max` becomes more complicated as there isn't just one single `FactorOfInterest` to look into there are 15. 

Is there a tidy way to address this (e.g. making use of a shared naming convention like `FactorOfInterest1`, `FactorOfInterest2`) or would I manually concatenate the cols containing the `FactorOfInterest` e.g. `which.max(all_data[c(15,30,45,60 ...)]))`

Comment: @SarahAshley Yes, the tidy way is to merge all these different factor columns into one, and adding a second column that describes *which* factor each row corresponds to. This can be accomplished easily by doing `your_data %>% gather(FactorName, FactorValue, ‹list of factor column names here›)`. This requires the ‹tidyr› package, which is closely related to ‹dplyr›.

Comment: I think `gather` is exactly what I am looking for. However, I have tried to gather for the `FactorOfInterest` using a column (`record`) that describes _which_ factor each row corresponds to and still run across some issues. I am not getting an output grouped by the descriptive column `record` as expected. 
I am using the following code:
`gathered_data <- gather(my_data, key=record, value = factor, -record)`
I have also tried
`gathered_data <- gather(my_data, key=record, value = factor, FactorOfInterest)`

Comment: Never mind, I found the answer in the tidy data format page you linked. An excellent resource!